# Ajax replace spaces with +

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making an ajax call and I need any spaces to be replaced by plus signs (+). I'll show my code below, but currently I'm using .replace(), however, its only taking the first space and replacing it with a plus, but leaving all the rest. Any ideas?

```
    function getImages() {
  [].slice.call(arguments)
    .map(function(artist) {
      return artist.toString().replace(/\s+/, '+');
    })
    .forEach(function(artist) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/',
        data: 'method=artist.getinfo' +
          '&artist=' + artist +
          '&api_key=secret' +
          '&format=json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
          document.body.innerHTML += '<img src="' + data.artist.image[2]['#text'] + '" /><br>'
        },
        error: function(code, message) {
          alert('there was an error'+ message);
        }
      });
    });
}
var values = []
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.artist').each(function() {
    var self = $(this)
    values.push(self.html());
  });

  getImages(values);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change this:

```
return artist.toString().replace(/\s+/, '+');
```

...to:

```
return artist.toString().replace(/\s+/g, '+');
```

The `g` flag will tell `replace` to do a "global" replace instead of just replacing the first match.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I didn't realize it before, but all my strings had a space (now a +) at the end. I tried to fix this by adding .slice(0,-1) to the end of that statement, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: You could trim before doing the replace. Since older browsers don't have the trim method, I find this handy to replace leading/trailing spaces:
`.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the .replace regex you posted

try

```
 .replace(/\s+/g"+");
```